# Bounds and Region not working to restrict map search

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, bounds

I have setup a simple geocode to verify an address. But both the Region and the Bounds don't seem to restrict.

My location that i'm search for is "2400 boston st" which is where I'm currently sitting in Baltimore MD.  On google maps if i search for 2400 boston st it guesses the right one. But with my geocoder code it guesses Boston, MA

```
validateAddress: function(address, callback) {
    var lat = this.current.lat;
    var lon = this.current.lon;
    var nMiles = 5;
    var m = 1/69;

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(lat + (m * nMiles), lon - (m * nMiles)),
        new google.maps.LatLng(lat - (m * nMiles), lon + (m * nMiles))
    );
    this.google.geocoder.geocode({
        address:address,
        bounds:bounds,
        region: "US"
    }, function (results, status) {
        if(!results || (results && !results.length)) return callback(false);
        else return callback(results[0].formatted_address);
    });
}
```

Basically I'm getting the current location, and creating bounds out 5 miles from here. That should help narrow the search, but it doesn't seem to.

I've checked my bounds on google maps and they are right I believe. But it still doesn't restrict at all. I have to type in the city and / or zip and I really don't want that.

Here is a link to a working prototype.  Put in an address near you, one that google might get wrong if it didn't know where you were. And check console

http://jsfiddle.net/57hpV/7/

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: the bounds do not restrict

Comment: Looks like your bounds is backwards [LatLngBounds(sw?:LatLng, ne?:LatLng) | Constructs a rectangle from the points at its south-west and north-east corners.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds)

Comment: AH! yes. It wasn't backwards, I just had bad math. If you wanna answer I'll check that. The correct math is  new google.maps.LatLng(lat - (m * nMiles), lon - (m * nMiles)), new google.maps.LatLng(lat + (m * nMiles), lon + (m * nMiles))